# Checking a chest for a specific item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been watching video tutorials for using command blocks and browsed a bit on here before forming this question.

I've been trying to make a shop where a player puts a few emeralds, let's say 8, in a chest and they receive something, let's say an obsidian block. After a good amount of experimenting, the command that has come close to my solution is:

```
execute if block ~ ~ ~ chest{Items:[{id:"minecraft:emerald", count:8b}]}
```

I also used the variation: `execute unless block...`

I have a button to press it but it only registers the chest; regardless of whatever is inside of it (even executing if the chest is empty). I'm on 1.16, so I don't think the "/testforblock" command (as seen in other questions) works. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hey, next time when you want to put specific text in a line in code formatting, you can select the text and press the brackets icon found in the editor. When you want to put a specific line in code formatting, you can add 4 spaces at the beginning of the line or, again, select the entire line and press the brackets icon found in the editor (does the same thing).

Comment: Oh, thank you lol I just made this account today so I didn't know how that worked. Will do that next time.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried this in 1.16.5 and the only thing I changed was the c in `count` to uppercase:

```
execute if block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:chest{Items:[{id:"minecraft:emerald", Count:8b}]} run say hi
```

That works perfectly for me.